# How to use the Swift 3 selectors?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Up until now I have had this code

```
if UIScreen.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("scale")) {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale);
}else{...}
```

I didn't write this code, so I'm not sure what it's for, but it looks like they wanted to verify that `UIScreen.mainScreen()` in fact can have the variable `.scale`(?).

When looking at the `.scale`, it looks to me like this has been available since iOS 4.0. Since we support down to iOS 7, this shouldn't be necessary, right?

Anyway, this is not the current problem.
I am now having hundreds of warnings due to Xcode 7.3 towards Swift 3 with these new selector-instantiations or whatnot.

Xcode wants me to change this:

`Selector("scale")`

into

`#selector(NSDecimalNumberBehaviors.scale)`

Until now, all other selectors I have changed have been logical, like "change `Selector("hello")` into `#selector(MyClass.hello)`, but this `NSDecimal..` sounds a bit drastic. **Can I trust Xcode to pick the right selector?** I can't find `NSDecimalNumberBehaviors` anywhere connected to UIScreen.scale.. If I type `#selector(UIScreen.scale)` I get an error..

The only thing I know for sure is that if I CMD+click `scale` here: `NSDecimalNumberBehaviors.scale` and here: `UIScreen.mainScreen().scale` I end up in different places..

Comment: I would first highly recommend talking with the person(s) who wrote the code (or at least someone who might know what's going on) before making changes like this.

Comment: What's in the else condition? I don't see why scale could not be called on UIScreen, the official documentation states that this property is available since iOS 4 as you said.

Comment: ZGski, they no longer work here. @Gusta the else statement is simply `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in comments, this code is a vestigial remnant of attempts to support old iOS versions that not only are no longer relevant, but can't even be targeted when developing in Swift.

Just call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)` directly — the `scale` property exists on all iOS versions that you can target with Swift, so there's no need to check for it.

In fact, in general it's not a good idea to test for API availability using selector checks. A selector may exist on a version below the one you're targeting, but be private API with different behavior — so your check will succeed, but your code will not behave correctly. This is why the [`@available` and `#available` system](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID523) was introduced in Swift 2.

(Another upside of version-based availability checking: when an OS version gets old enough for you to drop support, it's much easier to find all the sites in your code that you can clean up. You don't have to remember which version which method/property became universal in.)

---

If *for some other reason* you need to form a `Selector` for `UIScreen.scale`... you can't use the `#selector` expression to do that in Swift 2.2, because `scale` is a property, not a method. In Swift 2.2, `#selector` takes a function/reference, and there's no way to get a reference to the underlying getter or setter method of a property. You'd still need to construct that selector from a string. To get around the warning, stash the string literal in a temporary:

```
let scale = "scale"
let selector = Selector(scale)
```

Or do some other dance that passes a string, but doesn't directly pass a string *literal*, to the `Selector` initializer:

```
let selector = Selector({"scale"}())
```

In Swift 3 there'll be [a special form of `#selector` for property getters/setters](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0064-property-selectors.md), but it hasn't landed yet.

Answer (score 3):

my two cents:

- 1) swift has a new sntax for selectors
- 2) compiler can safely detect methods based on:

  - n. of params
  - type of every param
  - result type (ONLY in pure swift, so let's forget it now)

let see 4 cases:

A)

```
..
        closeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doIt), for: .touchUpInside)
    }



func doIt(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("touched")
}


func doIt() {
    print("touched2 ")

}
```

Ambiguous use of 'doIt'

B)

```
closeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doIt), for: .touchUpInside)
}


//  func doIt(_ sender: UIButton) {
//      print("touched")
//  }


func doIt() {
    print("touched2 ")

}
```

it works, as compiler is able to detect the ONLY method that 
can match the signature

C)

```
closeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doIt(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func doIt(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("touched")
}


func doIt() {
    print("touched2 ")
}
```

it works, as compiler is able to detect the ONLY method that 
can match the signature.

D)

```
closeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doIt), for: .touchUpInside)
}


func doIt(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("touched")
}

/*
func doIt() {
    print("touched2 ")

}
*/
```

it works and:

- compiler is able to detect the ONLY method that can match the
  signature
- in debugger You will get the correct button reference too, as the
  UIButton CODE (in iOS libs) pushes the button address on the
  stack, as compiler does create a stack frame.

Comment: ooo... what? what is that supposed to be?

Comment: simply a recap about you can use them. do you think is wrong?